# Memory Leak in Struct C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a structure like this,

```
struct int * ramp_output (int * L10)
{
    int * r;
    r = L10;
    return(r);
}
```

Should I free the memory from L10 and r?

Comment: That's about 2000 kinds of wrong - no such thing as struct int, no such thing as a struct having a return.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have you actually coded and compiled this stuff?

Comment: @KevinDTimm I think he wants a function which returns a struct?

Comment: @Tushar - (struct int *)?  he's completely lost because he says 'I have a structure like this'

Comment: @KevinDTimm I know the return type is incorrect, I'm just trying to clarify the use of a return (function?) inside `ramp_output`.

Comment: This question reminds me of the `word` 'irregardless' :)

Comment: I just wanted to make it simple the actual code is like the following,

struct car{
   int lane;
   int x;
}

struct car * ramp_output (car * L10){
   car * r;
   r = L10;
   //some analysis on r
   return (r);
}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code won't compile with the stray "struct" in there. Deleting that, we can answer your question: it depends how the parameter was allocated, but in any case you should only do it once.

```
int main()
{
    int a[]  = { 1, 1, 1 };
    int i    = 42;
    int* pi1 = &i;
    int* pi2 = new int[10];
    int* pi3 = new int(42);
    std::vector<int> v( 10 );
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp( new int(42) );

    int* r1 = ramp_output(a);
    int* r2 = ramp_output(&i);
    int* r3 = ramp_output(pi1);
    int* r4 = ramp_output(pi2);
    int* r5 = ramp_output(pi3);
    int* r6 = ramp_output(&v[0]);
    int* r7 = ramp_output(sp.get());

    // what to dealloc? Only these
    delete [] pi2; // or delete [] r4; but not both!
    delete pi3;    // or delete    r5; but not both!
}
```

All the others clean up after themselves one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Structs do not take arguments or return values. If you remove the "struct" from the code, this will be valid (although trivial) function: it just returns a pointer to the same thing that it's parameter is a pointer to. You don't need to, or want to, free any memory.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, the only time you need to free memory in C++ is when you created it with the "new" keyword. For example,

```
int * test = new int;
```

In this case, the pointer "test" points to an integer on the heap that "someone" should delete. Who's responsible for deleting it depends on the design of your program, you shouldn't delete it if you pass the pointer to other functions and they store/use copies of it.

As for your example code, it doesn't really make any sense, so you'll have to tell us what you're trying to do exactly to help with that.